# Firefox title bar doesn't go away in fullscreen mode

Tags: debian, firefox, window-decorations

I just upgraded Iceweasel to Firefox 45.2.0 (with `apt-get dist-upgrade`) on my computer which runs Debian 8 (Stable). When I switch to fullscreen the window title bar doesn't go away. I didn't have this problem in Iceweasel. Any clues? I use the window manager Blackbox and fullscreen works correctly with other applications.

Answer (score 0):

It has been two years since the question was asked, however, recently I run into exactly same issue (running Firefox full screen on Blackbox).

This Github [issue](https://github.com/bbidulock/blackboxwm/issues/18) explains why it happens.

In short:
It is not a Firefox issue. It is a Blackbox issue. It can be fixed by applying [patch](https://gist.github.com/vl-80/091a51481ea3a7e353a0cd9b11d1bc67#file-fullscreen_titlebar-patch) given in the linked Github issue. Or, if you are not comfortable with changing source code and recompiling the Blackbox, the workaround is to:

1. Maximize the Firefox window **first**.
2. Enable fullscreen mode on Firefox.

In this case the title bar disappears.

Disclaimer: I created the linked issue and the patch.

Answer (score -1):

While in full screen mode, if you right-click at the very top of the screen, is there a checkmark in front of "Hide Toolbars"? If not, go ahead and click that to turn it back on. The corresponding preference in about:config is browser.fullscreen.autohide (default value is true).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, the problem is not that the *tool bar* doesn't go away; it's the window title bar (provided by the window manager) that keeps showing.